# How to decorate Google Line Chart using react-google-charts plugin

Tags: reactjs, google-visualization

I am using react-google-charts in my reactjs application to create google line chart. I don't find any detailed document for this plugin.

I have few questions:

a) How to specify scaleStepWidth?
b) How to create pointDot in Line Chart?

Answer (score 1):

```
To enable pointDot in line chart you have to just set "true" the points property option in configuration i-e 
"pointsVisible: true"

Moreover you can find an example of line chart here  
https://github.com/RakanNimer/react-google-charts/blob/HEAD/sandboxes/linechart/index.js

Other customization options if required then you can provide it in option property. for example just like below:

var options = {
                //title: 'Graph',
                //isStacked: true,
                //legend: { position: 'top', maxLines: 3 },
                width: chartwidth1 / 2 * 2,
                height:450,
                vAxis: {
                    gridlines: { count: 15 },                   
                  viewWindow: { min: -100000, max: 2000000},
                },
                //series: series,
                chartArea: {
                    top: '10%', // set this to adjust the legend width
                    left: '8%',  // set this eventually, to adjust the left margin
                    height: "80%",
                    width: "93%",
                    //width: "60%"
                },
                legend: { position: 'top', alignment: 'start' },
                pointsVisible: true
            }
```